# Copying subset of list string to another list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list (All_Date) that has certain dates in the format below. I want to copy only the DD to another list (All_Day). How do I use string subset with a list?

```
2020-10-14T00:00:00+00:00
```

```
public List<string> All_Date = new List<string>();
public List<string> All_Day = new List<string>();

void Start()
{
  All_Day = new List<string>(All_Date.Count);
}
```

Comment: c# List ConvertAll should do https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.convertall?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use `DateTime` like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

All_Day = All_Date.Select(d => DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd")).ToList();
```

Comment: @Ibrahim yeah I missed the culture info parameter ;)

Comment: Thank you derHugo. I have one more question. If the date-time is added such as the format ```"2020-04-17T02:00:00+00:00"```, then can I parse as ```DateTime.ParseExact(d, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ",....)```?

Comment: I am still stuck at this point. I do not know how to parse the date-time with the above timezone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this with regular expression, here is my answer :

```
public List<string> Do(List<string> dates)
{
   return dates.Select(date => Regex.Match(date, "([^\\-]+$)").Value).ToList();
}
```

Example :

```
var dates = new List<string>
{
     "2020-10-14",
     "2020-10-15",
     "2019-10-15",
     "2020-10-29"
 };

 var days = Do(dates);
```

Comment: Yes thank you. This works. Can you explain how you used Regex with ```[^\\-]+$```. I did not understand  this part.

Comment: YW, this part matches every character that comes after last dash (-). If you want deeper understanding, I suggest you try some online curses about regular expression.(btw I never learned Regex)